# Is it possible to display 2D view of Multiple Revit models together in viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have created one web viewer which displays multiple revit models in 3D view but i am not able to see 2D view of all Revit models.

Is there any way so i can change 3D view to 2D view using Autodesk Forge API. Requirement is to be able to see 2D view for all the models at the same time in the same view.

Comment: I am trying to understanding correctly. Are you looking for way to load only one 2D view in Forge Viewer , or aggregate 2D views in one Viewer, or aggregate 3D view with 2D view in the same viewer?

Comment: Requirement is to be able to see 2D view for all the models at the same time in the same view.

Comment: My apology for the delay response! I missed your message. It sounds you wanted to aggregate 2D views in one Viewer. The logic of 2D is similar to 3D, you only need to get 2D viewable data, and load them one by one. I'd recommend the utility my colleague produced: https://github.com/yiskang/MultipleModelUtil. If you still have problem, could you share a source model? I can try to build a demo code. Please email us at forge.help@autodesk.com  with download link of the private source model.

Comment: And one more latest blog I would recommend is https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7. It also models aggregating 3D model on 2D view.